# Excel macro to find a date in a range and then count for next value change in an adjacent column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, vba

I am attempting to write a macro to find February 2nd of each year in column A and then count the number of rows (days) until the value in column B changes. This count could be put in a new column, column C, but on the same row as the February 2nd that it correlates to, in this case row 3.

Using the table below the output to C3 would be 5. I am not counting the day of February 2nd but I am counting the day the change occurs. This is for 100+ years that I will need to loop through.

```
id |      A     |  B  |  C  
----------------------------
 1 | 1946/01/31 |  0  |  
 2 | 1946/02/01 |  0  |
 3 | 1946/02/02 |  0  |
 4 | 1946/02/03 |  0  |
 5 | 1946/02/04 |  0  |
 6 | 1946/02/05 |  0  |
 7 | 1946/02/06 |  0  |
 8 | 1946/02/07 |  2  |
 9 | 1946/02/08 |  0  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real challenge is to do it with a formula. Well, 2 formulas.

[image: screenshot]

The first formula in cell E2 finds the date 2nd Feb by looking for "02/02" at the end of the text in column B and if it is found it places the contents of C2 in that cell. if it's not found it compares C1 with D1, the 2 cells above to see if they are the same because a match was previously found and if so it takes the contents of the cell above.  This results in the zeros you can see in column E between 2nd Feb and the point where column C changes.

Formula for E2 and then autofill down to the end of your data

```
=IF(AND(MONTH(B2)=2,DAY(B2)=2),C1,IF(AND(E1<>"",E1=C1),E1,""))
```

Now all we need to do is count the cells in column D by looking for the first non blank cell in column D `AND(E1="",E2<>"")` and then count all the cells that match that cell.  I'm not sure what gap you're expecting to find but you can change the 200 to ensure that you count everything.  The last part is to take away 1 so that the 2nd feb row is not being counted.

Formula for D2 and then autofill down to the end of your data

```
=if(AND(E1="",E2<>""),countif(E2:E200,E2)-1,"")
```

Comment: Thanks for the formulas Gordon. I plugged these in and tried a few modifications but couldn't get the same output you are getting in your screenshot. I am getting this: http://imgur.com/a/h3Qz9

Comment: The reason it's not working is because when I did my example in Google Sheets the dates were not recognised as dates so I used the `right("02/02"` I've copied it to excel and and it converts automatically to dates so it no longer works.  It's not dificult to fix, just need a different way to find the 2nd Feb.

Comment: I've updated the formula for column E so that it checks the date properly and also checks itself with column C instead of Column D as I think I copied a formula from the wrong cell before.  It should work now.